# How to change error page in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I have a method, that allowed only post `requests`. When i send send `get` request, i get a standard error page.

Can i change it or make redirect for another page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`errorhandler` decorator](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.Flask.errorhandler) to provide custom handling of a 405 error.

```
from flask import render_template

@app.errorhandler(405)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('405.html'), 405
```

Comment: Thanks, @app.errorhandler more pretty decision in my situation :)